# MySQL INSERT multiple rows depending on result from SELECTing other table

Tags: mysql, select, insert

The following query gives me a result of different IDs from the table `one` depending on `condition`:

`SELECT id FROM one WHERE condition`

I need to use these ids to insert data into another table:

```
INSERT INTO two (id, col1, col2) VALUES
(1st-id-from-above, 'foo','bar'),
(2nd-id-from-above, 'foo','bar'),
…
(last-id-from-above, 'foo','bar');
```

`'foo'`and `'bar'` is always the same, they’re static. The only dynamic things are:

- the number of IDs (i.e. the number of rows to insert into `two`),
- the IDs itself (i.e. the values to insert into the first column of `two`).

How can I do the job automatically?

The two tables are not identical, so I’m not dealing with moving rows from one table to another.

Comment: INSERT INTO two SELECT ... ?

Comment: @Strawberry: gives me »Subquery returns more than 1 row.« Maybe my syntax is incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO two (id, col1, col2)
SELECT id, 'foo', 'bar'
FROM one 
WHERE condition
```

Comment: In the meanwhile I figured it out by myself but thanks anyway. This answer is purely correct. :)